# Bug in my backtracking code - Bridge Crossing

Tags: c++, algorithm, backtracking

I'm trying to learn backtracking and for that purpose I picked one of TopCoder problems - its called BridgeCrossing. We have 1-6 people trying to cross the bridge at night and there is one flashlight between them. At most 2 people can cross the bridge at once and when they're doing that, at least one of them must have a flashlight, otherwise they won't see anything...

The answer is a function that given a `vector <int> times` where `times[i-1]` represent time needed for i-th person to cross the bridge (when 2 people are crossing the bridge their time is the one coming from the slower person). Also, when we have flashlight on the other side of the bridge and there are still some people that need to cross the bridge - one person must return with a flashlight in order to guide them through.

Here's my solution (all occurences of `vector <int>` are made into `VI`):

```
int backtrack(VI times){
        if (times.empty()) return 0;
        if (times.size() == 1) return times[0];
        if (times.size() == 2) return max(times[0], times[1]);
        VI results;
        for (int i = 0; i < times.size(); i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
                VI people_left1;
                for (int k = 0; k < times.size(); k++){
                    if (k != i && k != j){
                        people_left1.push_back(times[k]);
                    }
                }
                people_left1.push_back(min(times[i], times[j]));
                results.push_back(backtrack(people_left1)+
                max(times[i], times[j]) + min(times[i], times[j]));
            }
            for (int j= i + 1; j < times.size(); j++){
                VI people_left;
                for (int k = 0; k < times.size(); k++){
                    if (k != i && k != j){
                        people_left.push_back(times[k]);
                    }
                }
                people_left.push_back(min(times[i], times[j]));
                results.push_back(backtrack(people_left)+
                max(times[i], times[j]) + min(times[i], times[j]));
            }
        }
        int res = INT_MAX;
        for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++){
            if (results[i] < res){
                res = results[i];
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Theoretically it should work well - I'm picking all possible pairs of indices i,j, guide one person (with larger time) through, return with one person and recurse on the people left. Unfortunately it doesn't work - for input `{1,2,5,10}` it should return 17, but my function outputs 19.

I've been staring at this code for quite a time now, and I still can't see any bugs. Where could one be hiding? Also, what are techniques for debugging such recursive functions as I've been having problems with doing that for quite a time now.

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger, while watching the values of the involved variables. When something seems out of place, it probably is.

Comment: The problem with debugging backtracking code with a debugger is that recursion depth is pretty deep and usually I can't "imagine" what is going on now and what SHOULD be going now...

Comment: You can visualize it by adding some vertical lines as "depth" and horizontal arrow drawingas as people crossing bridges.

Comment: @quibit - the problem is that a person who is not a part from the i,j pair can return with the flashlight. This is a person who was on the other side way before i,j went there. You always consider that either i or j will return with the flashlight which is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't consider that a person who has already remained on the other side can in the future return with the flashlight. In the example case person number 2 returns after some time. Basically not always a person from the i,j pair will return with the flashlight.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer but your code could be more readable by doing this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < times.size(); j++){
    if (j != i) {
    .. all that code inside both loops               
    }
}
```

Maybe that would make it easier to find your issue.

You can debug recursive code, sometimes, by printing info indented according to the level of recursion. To do this you have to add a variable that is passed down each level. Increment it when you call down a level.

```
method(int level, ...) {
    if (recursing needed) {
         print(spaces(level * 3) + "recursing");
         method(level + 1);
    }
}
```